# открытие файлов и исполнения кода. Subprocess python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

День добрый господа! Есть код который открывает файлы .py

```
import subprocess


files = ["sqlite_connect.py", "sqlite_connect1.py"]  # файлы, которые нужно запустить
for file in files:
    subprocess.Popen(args=["start", "python", file], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Проблема в том, что код в файлах исполняется частично, а сами терминалы и соответственно програмки  закрываются. В самих файлах циклы.  Поогите найти решения проблемы , нужно чтобы полностью файлы исполнялись.

Comment: Использовать [Popen.wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) чтобы дождаться завершения процессов.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий... Я только учу данную тему, можете приложить пример кода, а то я не могу понять как применить ваш ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, процессы запущенные из вашего кода должны отрабатывать до конца. Хотя родительский процесс и завершится не дожидаясь их окончания.

Чтобы дождаться их завершения:

1. Надо добавить опцию `/WAIT` команде `start`, а то иначе уже она не будет ждать завершения запущенного из-под неё питоновского интерпретатора.
2. Использовать [`Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) чтобы дождаться завершения процессов.

```
import subprocess

files = ["sqlite_connect.py", "sqlite_connect1.py"]  # файлы, которые нужно запустить

# запускаем процессы
procs = [subprocess.Popen(args=["start", "/WAIT", "python", file], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) for file in files]
print(f"Запущено {len(procs)} процессов")

# ждём их завершения
while procs:
    procs.pop().wait()
    print(f"Осталось {len(procs)} процессов")

print("Конец")
```

Если запускать python напрямую (без использования start), то тоже должно работать. Правда в этом случае вы не увидите терминалов дочерних процессов.

Comment: это супер) ваше решение работает) Спасибо вам!